# Looking for example on how to calculate complexity of O (n log n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am new to Data Structures and have been trying to grasp the concepts. I understand Big - O notation, and looking for examples relate to O(n log n). I searched the internet but haven't got a satisfied example or implementation - where in I can see complexity of O(n log n).
Can some one point me to a better example and implementation for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The title is "how to calculate" but then you say you're "looking for examples" and then ask for a "satisfied example or implementation" where you can "see complexity of O(n log n)". The functions f(n)=n log n, f(n)=n, f(n)=1 are all O(n log n). Many efficient sorting algorithms perform O(n log n) comparisons. What is the specific problem you have?

Comment: I am learning and I posted this question. I was looking for more examples of O(n log n). Thanks I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a well known theorem in complexity theory called the *Master theorem*. Its particular case says that if the complexity `T(n)` of an algorithm satisfies the equation

```
  T(n) = a T(n/a) + b*n           (1)
```

then

```
  T(n) = O (n log n)              (2)
```

The equation (1) above can be interpreted as though the algorithm works by splitting the problem into `a` parts and applying itself to each part separately and then doing some work on the complete input. This algorithmic pattern is sometimes called *Merge and Recombine*.

Consider the following example in Python

```python
 def f(x):
     if len(x) > 1:
         x1 = [z for z in x[1:] if z <= x[0]]
         x2 = [z for z in x[1:] if z > x[0]]
         return f(x1) + [x[0]] + f(x2)
     else:
         return x
```

this function implements a recursive algorithm that splits the input list into two parts and applies itself to each part independently, then concatenates the results. If we are lucky and `x` and `y` parts are of the same length then the complexity of the algorithm can be computed with the formula `(2)` above with `a = 2`.

If you are familiar with sorting and the Python language, you would recognize here an algorithm that emulates Quicksort but without the complexity of performing the sorting inplace. A somewhat cleaner example is Merge sort mentioned in the answer given by Christos.

Answer (score 3):

A classic example of an `O(nlogn)` algorithm is this of [Merge Sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/). [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297160/why-is-mergesort-olog-n) you would find a detailed calculation of it's complexity. Generally speaking, there are many [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) algorithms that have this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the Cormen's **Introduction to Algorithms** Page-151 (Heapsort) and 170 (Quicksort). These are explained in detail in this book. The key idea in every case is that you need to understand the basic operation that is being done which is the comparison (in this two cases) and then analyze using the feature of the algorithm itself. For quicksort the pivottal analysis and for heapsort the heapify part.

This book covers everything you need to know in order to analyze complexity.